# Define a new block environment in LaTeX beamer

Tags: beamer, environments

I have two kinds of examples in my document. I want to use different colors, say, red and blue. This is what I am doing now.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=red!75!black}
\begin{block}{First Kind Example}
This is example of the first kind.
\end{block}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=blue!75!black}
\begin{block}{Second Kind Example}
This is example of the second kind.
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I know this is kind of stupid. I want to define two new block environments, one for each color, so I don't need to use `setbeamercolor` every time I use them.

```
\begin{block1}{First Kind Example}
...
\end{block1}
\begin{block2}{Second Kind Example}
...
\end{block2}
```

I know I need to define these two new environments in the preamble, but don't know how. Thanks for the help.

By the way, what is a good reference on these kinds of tricks in LaTeX/beamer? Any recommendations?

[image]

Comment: Beamer itself defines three types of blocks: `block`, `alertblock` and `exampleblock`. You can customize them separately.

Comment: Here is the beamer user guide http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want to present them as examples and mark them up as such using beamer's `example` environment (rather than just using the generic `block`) you might try something like this:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\newtheorem{examplefirst}{Example}
\newtheorem{examplesecond}{Example}
\newenvironment<>{examplefirst}[1][]{%
  \setbeamercolor{block title example}{fg=white,bg=red!75!black}%
  \begin{example}#2[#1]}{\end{example}}
\newenvironment<>{examplesecond}[1][]{%
  \setbeamercolor{block title example}{fg=white,bg=blue!75!black}%
  \begin{example}#2[#1]}{\end{example}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{examplefirst}[An example of the first kind]
        Something about this example of the first kind.
    \end{examplefirst}
    \begin{examplesecond}[An example of the second kind]
        Something about this example of the second kind.
    \end{examplesecond}
    \begin{example}[A regular example]
        Something about the regular example.
    \end{example}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: 3 kinds of example environment]

If you prefer to stick to the generic `block` environment perhaps something like this might work:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\newenvironment<>{examplefirst}[1]{%
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=red!75!black}%
  \begin{block}#2{#1}}{\end{block}}
\newenvironment<>{examplesecond}[1]{%
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=blue!75!black}%
  \begin{block}#2{#1}}{\end{block}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{examplefirst}{An example of the first kind}
        Something about this example of the first kind.
    \end{examplefirst}
    \begin{examplesecond}{An example of the second kind}
        Something about this example of the second kind.
    \end{examplesecond}
    \begin{block}{A regular block}
        Something in the regular block format.
    \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @cfr, Could you explain you command for new environment?  For example, what are `<>` for?

Comment: @Royi It makes the environment overlay-specification-aware. See Beamer's manual for details - it changes `\newcommand` and `\newenvironment` and friends in this way.

Comment: May I also ask how come you use `#2` while you define only 1 parameter for the environment? Thank You.

Comment: @Royi That's for the overlay specification.

Comment: What is the difference between the both solutions?

Comment: @Ben Please read my answer. I explained the difference already.

Comment: The output is the same, isn't it? Which solution should be preferred? What does "mark them up as examples" do for me?

Comment: @Ben The output is not generally the same. See the output I posted above. Of course, you may be using a theme which merges the two, so that the output is the same in your case. But that's not the default and not true for most themes. Again, look at the output I posted: it is clearly different. Exactly how the output differs depends on your choice of theme(s).

Answer (score 6):

Here you have the standard code, using different colors

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{whale}
\usecolortheme{orchid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A frame}

\begin{block}{A block environment}
Some text.
\end{block}

\begin{alertblock}{An alertblock environment}
Some text.
\end{alertblock}

\begin{exampleblock}{An exampleblock environment}
Some text.
\end{exampleblock}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: You can add the code needed for customization: it would make your answer more complete.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino yes, but I just know their is a standard code giving the answer to his problem. But I will look further, because a this moment, I don't know yet how to change it.

Comment: Excellent! You can start with the manual, looking section 12.3 Block Environments and how to change the templates' aspect via `\setbeamercolor`. +1 meanwhile :)

Answer (score 1):

Extended versuion of @cfr's answer:

```
\newenvironment<>{definition}[2][DEFINITION]{%
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg= green}%
    \setbeamerfont{block title example}{family=\ssfamily}
    \begin{block}{#1}#3{#2}}{\end{block}}
```

and use it as

```
\begin{definition}
some text
\end{definition}
```

that its title by default is: `DEFINITION`

or you can give your title:

```
\begin{definition}[YOUR TITLE]
    some text
\end{definition}
```

[image]