# Wrong vertical spaces using bibentry within beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, bibliographies, bibentry

I would like to give some references using the `bibentry` package in a beamer presentation. But sometimes, e.g. if the list of authors spans over multiple lines, there is a wrong vertical space in the output (see Image below). Is there a way to adjust the wrong spacing?
[image]

Here the corresponding MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
    @article{RefA, 
        author  = {AFirstName ALastName}, 
        title   = {Title A}, 
        journal = {Journal A}, 
        volume  = {1},
        pages   = {345--678},
        year    = {9999}, 
    } 
    @article{RefB, 
        author  = {BFirstName BLastName}, 
        title   = {Title B}, 
        journal = {Journal B}, 
        volume  = {1},
        pages   = {345--678},
        year    = {9999}, 
    } 
    @article{Problem, 
        author  = {ProblemFirstName ProblemLastName and NoSolutionFirstName NoSolutionLastName}, 
        title   = {Title Problem}, 
        journal = {Journal Problem}, 
        volume  = {1},
        pages   = {345--678},
        year    = {9999}, 
    }  
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Bibentry -- Spacing Problem}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \bibentry{RefA}
        \item \bibentry{RefB}
        \item \bibentry{Problem}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Bibliography -- No Problem}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `beamer`s definition of `\newblock` which is used between units of the citation.  Its definition, in `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`, ends with some code that is unnecessary for your inline use.  The strange spacing occurs whenever the text before the first new block (the author part) spans more than one line.

Therefore you need to make a version of `\newblock` that does the font changing `beamer` provides, but without the final code.  This is for use in the main text.  When you get to the bibliography you should restore the original `beamer` definition which is in `\beamer@newblock`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
    @article{RefA, 
        author  = {AFirstName ALastName}, 
        title   = {Title A}, 
        journal = {Journal A}, 
        volume  = {1},
        pages   = {345--678},
        year    = {9999}, 
    } 
    @article{RefB, 
        author  = {BFirstName BLastName}, 
        title   = {Title B}, 
        journal = {Journal B}, 
        volume  = {1},
        pages   = {345--678},
        year    = {9999}, 
    } 
    @article{Problem, 
        author  = {ProblemFirstName ProblemLastName and NoSolutionFirstName NoSolutionLastName}, 
        title   = {Title Problem}, 
        journal = {Journal Problem}, 
        volume  = {1},
        pages   = {345--678},
        year    = {9999}, 
    }  
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*

\def\mybeamernewblock{%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry author}%
  \usebeamerfont{bibliography entry author}%
  \usebeamertemplate{bibliography entry author}%
  \def\newblock{%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry title}%
    \usebeamerfont{bibliography entry title}%
    \usebeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}%
    \def\newblock{%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry location}%
      \usebeamerfont{bibliography entry location}%
      \usebeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}%
      \def\newblock{%
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry note}%
        \usebeamerfont{bibliography entry note}%
        \usebeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}}}}%
  \leavevmode
}

\begin{document}

\let\newblock\mybeamernewblock
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Bibentry -- Spacing Problem}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \bibentry{RefA}
        \item \bibentry{RefB}
        \item \bibentry{Problem}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\makeatletter
\let\newblock\beamer@newblock
\makeatother
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Bibliography -- No Problem}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

*Update* This may be packaged as an environment for use in the body keeping the change local as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 
    @article{RefA, 
        author  = {AFirstName ALastName}, 
        title   = {Title A}, 
        journal = {Journal A}, 
        volume  = {1},
        pages   = {345--678},
        year    = {9999}, 
    } 
    @article{RefB, 
        author  = {BFirstName BLastName}, 
        title   = {Title B}, 
        journal = {Journal B}, 
        volume  = {1},
        pages   = {345--678},
        year    = {9999}, 
    } 
    @article{Problem, 
        author  = {ProblemFirstName ProblemLastName and NoSolutionFirstName NoSolutionLastName}, 
        title   = {Title Problem}, 
        journal = {Journal Problem}, 
        volume  = {1},
        pages   = {345--678},
        year    = {9999}, 
    }  
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*

\def\mybeamernewblock{%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry author}%
  \usebeamerfont{bibliography entry author}%
  \usebeamertemplate{bibliography entry author}%
  \def\newblock{%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry title}%
    \usebeamerfont{bibliography entry title}%
    \usebeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}%
    \def\newblock{%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry location}%
      \usebeamerfont{bibliography entry location}%
      \usebeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}%
      \def\newblock{%
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{bibliography entry note}%
        \usebeamerfont{bibliography entry note}%
        \usebeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}}}}%
  \leavevmode
}

\newenvironment{references}{\begin{itemize}\let\newblock\mybeamernewblock}{\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Bibentry -- Spacing Problem}
    \begin{references}
        \item \bibentry{RefA}
        \item \bibentry{RefB}
        \item \bibentry{Problem}
    \end{references}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Bibliography -- No Problem}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can these be made into an environment, so I can just do `\begin{references} \bibentry{bla} \end{references}`? I tried, modifying the code [in this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152565/define-a-new-block-environment-in-latex-beamer), but failed miserably... Right now I'm going for a modification of my bst file, according to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205112/beamer-and-bibentry).

Comment: @rubenvb No problem - I have added a version doing this to my solution.