# Beamer and Bibentry

Tags: beamer, bibtex

In a Beamer-Presentation I use Bibentry to print selected articles etc.

I have one problem: the title of each bibliographic entry is displayed as a hyperreference with a break afterwards.

[image: ouput]

How can I switch this off?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{pwaLiterature.bib}
    @incollection{Garner2009,
        Address = {Oxford and New York, NY},
        Author = {Garner, Robert},
        Booktitle = {Introduction to Politics},
        Date-Added = {2014-10-06 07:40:47 +0000},
        Date-Modified = {2014-10-06 07:42:45 +0000},
        Editor = {Garner, Robert and Ferdinand, Peter and Lawson, Stephanie},
        Pages = {1-21},
        Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
        Title = {Introduction: The Nature of Politics and Political Analysis},
        Year = {2009}}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\nobibliography*

\frame{\frametitle{}
\begin{tabular}{p{.15\textwidth} p{.85\textwidth}}
                &   \hangindent=0.5cm \bibentry{Garner2009}.\\
\end{tabular}
}

\bibliographystyle{apalike2}
\nobibliography{pwaLiterature}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The first edit isn't a minimal example yet. Please start by commenting out (and then removing) extra commands from the preamble, changing the bibliography style to something standard, and using a `filecontents` environment to show what goes in a single-item file the `\bibitem` is included from. It appears that the `\newblock` commands are responsible for the breaks, but no idea where a hyperlink would come from, or what it points to. As you make each change, see if the problem persists on recompiles. Eventually, you'll have a block of code that is much easier to analyze and test.

Comment: @MikeRenfo I've helped to feder80, I made MWE for him, but I could not help him with an answer:(

Comment: Thank you @saldenisov, now I know how to do it right the next time.

Answer (score 3):

As Mike Renfro has already mentioned, the problem has something to do with the citation style, in this case apalike2.

The function for "incollection" is as follows:

```
FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output              % special for
  output.year.check                 % apalike
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { eho.format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
    % The above line is changed by Eric Ho <eho@word> on Fri Jan 12
    % 19:20:28 1990 so that it'll call eho.format.in.ed.booktitle instead
    % of format.in.ed.booktitle.

      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.chapter.pages eho.special.output
      new.sentence
%      publisher "publisher" output.check
%      address output
% switched order of publisher and address for incollection -- BJR 1/3/90
      address eho.output    % Use eho.output instead of output.
      publisher "publisher" eho.output.check    % Use eho.output.check instead
                        % of output.check.
      format.edition output
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.chapter.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

This function called new.block must be the one, which is responsible for the break:

```
FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.block 'output.state := }
  if$
}
```

By deleting it, I get the right output.

But why does the problem (without modifying apalike2) only appear in the beamer but not the article class?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{pwaLiterature.bib}
    @incollection{Garner2009,
        Address = {Oxford and New York, NY},
        Author = {Garner, Robert},
        Booktitle = {Introduction to Politics},
        Date-Added = {2014-10-06 07:40:47 +0000},
        Date-Modified = {2014-10-06 07:42:45 +0000},
        Editor = {Garner, Robert and Ferdinand, Peter and Lawson, Stephanie},
        Pages = {1-21},
        Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
        Title = {Introduction: The Nature of Politics and Political Analysis},
        Year = {2009}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\nobibliography*
\begin{tabular}{p{.15\textwidth} p{.85\textwidth}}
            &   \hangindent=0.5cm \bibentry{Garner2009}.\\
\end{tabular}

\bibliographystyle{apalike2}
\nobibliography{pwaLiterature}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment `new.block`:

```
FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output              % special for
  output.year.check                 % apalike
  %new.block<-----------commented!!!!!!
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$....
```

Comment: Yes, as I have written in the answer to my question: by deleting (or commenting) the new.block parts, I get the right output. However, the question is still unanswered, why the beamer and the article class produce different outputs with the original style-file (including the new.block function).