# Example name in beamer

Tags: beamer

How to change example name in beamer to some custom name (eg. Primer) without using exampleblock environment?
It would be even better if it were possible to define new environment (with custom name, eg. primer) which behave same as example environment.

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
 \mode<presentation> {
   \usetheme{Darmstadt}
   \setbeamercovered{transparent} 
  %\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
   \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
  } 
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
  \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
  \begin{document} 
    \begin{frame} 
      \begin{exampleblock}{Primer} Test \end{exampleblock} 
    \end{frame} 
  \end{document}
```

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152580/36296