# Beamer \newenviroment problem when new block starts with displayed equation using Copenhagen theme

Tags: beamer, themes, displaystyle

I've modified answer of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152580/241755) for new blocks as follow but when I put an displayed equation as first line it produce error `Extra }, or forgotten $. ^^I\end{frame}` and when I put it after an empty line the error goes away. What exactly is the problem?

What I figured out this problem is related to `Copenhagen` theme!

**P.s. 1** Mathematical `align` environment produce a different error!

**P.s. 2** usual block has no such problem!

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\newenvironment<>{theorem}[2][Theorem]{%
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg= red!90!blue}%
\begin{block}{#1}#3{#2}}{\end{block}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{theorem} 
        this is OK!
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{theorem}%<-- error
        \[x^2=y^2+z^2\]
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{theorem}%<-- OK

        \[x^2=y^2+z^2\]
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{block}{theorem}%<-- OK
        \[x^2=y^2+z^2\]
    \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

My goal is to have an theorem block with one optional argument when is not empty this become the block title something like as follow:

```
\begin{theorem}
     \[x^2=y^2+z^2\]
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}[MY TITLE]
     \[x^2=y^2+z^2\]
\end{theorem}
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't your `theorem` env take two arguments on one optional and one mandatory. And you are not giving the mandatory one

Comment: I don't know what mandatory one is. I just copied it.

Comment: `\newenvironment<>{theorem}[2][Theorem]` the `[2]` says this takes two arguments. `[Theorem]` says the first is optional.

Comment: I know what you say but the linked post accept one argument  without my optional one. (see linked post)

Comment: (1) The `Copenhagen` theme is not related. (2) if you use ` \begin{theorem}{test}` the it compiles just fine. Your problem with not specifying the mandatory arg is that `begin{theorem}` then tries to use `\[` as its argument and then math fails. You might just want to change `[2]` to `[1]`

Comment: And note how all those in the linked example used `[1]`, where did that `[2]` come from?

Comment: I've added that extra option to be optional. Can one have optional argument without my `[2]` and just using linked post?

Comment: Not with that syntax it only supports a single optional argument. You should probably start over and rephrase your question to explain what your end goal is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\newenvironment<>{theorem}[1][Theorem]{%
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg= red!90!blue}%
    \begin{block}#2{#1}
}{
    \end{block}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{theorem}<1->
         \[x^2=y^2+z^2\]
    \end{theorem}
    
    \begin{theorem}<2->[MY TITLE]
         \[x^2=y^2+z^2\]
    \end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here you define one optional argument which has default value `Theorem`. If you specify another title by `[MY TITLE]`, this one will be used.

Thanks to your comment, it now obeys overlay specifications.

[image: Result]

Comment: Shouldn't we care about the overlay specification? as it has been said and used in linked post?

Comment: Probably we should, thanks for mentioning! I was not aware of this, I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, simply use the default theorem environment provided by beamer. It will accept an optional title just fine - no changes necessary.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{theorem} 
        this is OK!
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{theorem}
        \[x^2=y^2+z^2\]
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{theorem}[test]

        \[x^2=y^2+z^2\]
    \end{theorem}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you don't like that the optional title is shown in `()`, you can change the `theorem begin` template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{%
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=red!90!blue}%
  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
  {%
    \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty
      \inserttheoremname
    \else
      \inserttheoremaddition
    \fi%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{theorem} 
        this is OK!
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{theorem}
        \[x^2=y^2+z^2\]
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{theorem}[test]

        \[x^2=y^2+z^2\]
    \end{theorem}
    
    \begin{block}{title}
    content...
    \end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]